# Parsing through PHP file with Java to get Coordinates using JSON

Tags: java, android, json

There is a PHP file hosted on the server that looks like this:

```
[{"address":"12345 State St.","city":"Chicago","state":"IL","zip":"60610","name":"Home","phone":"8155555555","web":"http:\/\/www.websitetitle.org"......]
```

and I need to grab the data from this .php file, store it in a JSON array (i believe I was told) and then pull the data into my code so that i can use the lat and longs to pin on maps.

I have no idea where to even begin, im new to JSON and I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction.

EDIT: Working in Java with the php hosted on a url

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

First thing you need to do is decode it

```
$json_data = '[{"address":"12345 State St.","city":"Chicago","state":"IL","zip":"60610","name":"Home","phone":"8155555555","web":"http:\/\/www.websitetitle.org"......]';
$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

Then you'll have access to it's contents in PHP

Do a var_dump to see what you've got, and go from there

```
var_dump($data);
```

You'll likely end up with something like this:

```
$lat = $data->lat;
$lng = $data->lng;
```

### JAVA

If you want to do the same with java, you'll need to use a library for this, head to http://www.json.org/ and choose one from the java section at the bottom of the page, and follow their instructions.

Comment: IM sorry, I should mentiont that the PHP is hosted online and I am fetching it via url into the Java code

Comment: answer updated to point you in the right track

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JSONObject class.

Have a look at this previous post. [Android - How to parse JSONObject and JSONArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350540/android-how-to-parse-jsonobject-and-jsonarrays)