# Fetching PNR status from PNR no. using json

Tags: java, android, json

> **I am android beginner and trying to fetch pnr status using json here is my code which is not working please help me .**
>   Also tell me which parsing method is goo xml parse or json parse.
>   When you asking questions, using some more words to describe your problem will always help. If there are really nothing more to say, just copy some random paragraph from internet, but make sure you mark them as dummy text so that people won't pay attention on them.

```
 public class JSON extends Activity {
    String completeData="";
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    Button bt;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject jsonobj;
    final static String URI="http://pnrapi.alagu.net/api/v1.0/pnr/";
    String pnr_no=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        client=new DefaultHttpClient();

    }

    public void showpnr(View v){
        pnr_no=et.getText().toString();
        if(pnr_no.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter the Valid Pnr", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
            GetPNR pnr=new GetPNR();
            pnr.execute("train-name");
            completeData="";
        }
        public JSONArray pnr(String username){
            JSONArray jarray=null;
            try 
            {
                StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(URI);
                builder.append(username);
                HttpGet get=new HttpGet(builder.toString());
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);
                int status =response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(status==200){
                    HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                    String data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    jarray=new JSONArray(data);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jarray;
        }


    JSONObject js_pnr=new JSONObject();
    public class GetPNR extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String>>
{



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText("Loading Pnr status");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> al_texts=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            JSONArray data =pnr(pnr_no);
            if(data==null){
                return null;
            }
            int count=data.length();
            JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                jobj=data.getJSONObject(i);
                al_texts.add(jobj.getString("train-name").toString());
            }
            return al_texts;
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> al_pnrText) {
        if(al_pnrText==null){
            tv.setText("Pnr not found");
            return;
        }
        for(String string:al_pnrText){
            completeData+=string+System.getProperty("line.seperator")
                          +System.getProperty("line.seperator");
        }
        tv.setText("pnr status:"+System.getProperty("line.seperator")+completeData);
        }
}   
}
```

Comment: IS there a specific exception that you are getting?

Comment: no i am no getting any exception it won't work. it always toast pnr not found

Comment: Ok.i'm checking your code now. first tell me where is your button onclicklistener.

Comment: instead of using onclicklistner i use onclick in xml file

Comment: ok..but your url returns jsonobject,but why you returning jsonarray here.

Comment: by copy and paste your url(+ a name), i'm getting like this {"status":"OK","data":{}} ...is this your returning data.. or anything extra

Comment: can you provide me the valid returning jason page, so i can help you.

Comment: I am beginner may be some where i am doing wrong coding just tell me how can i correct these code. it always displayed pnr not found.

Comment: http://pnrapi.alagu.net/api/v1.0/pnr/2823421720

Comment: the above link gives you the valid returning json page

Comment: Check this ans[Android - How to parse JSONObject and JSONArrays][1] . it will help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350540/android-how-to-parse-jsonobject-and-jsonarrays

Comment: can you please correct this code this will help me a lot in understanding the parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your button onclick just write:

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String details = "";
            GetPNR pnrDetails = new GetPNR();
            try {
                details = pnrDetails.execute(URI+et.getText().toString()).get();


                    Log.d("train", details);
                    tv.setText(details);


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

And the Asynctask is like:

```
public class GetPNR extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String al_texts = "";

        for(String newUrl:params){
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(newUrl);
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = client.execute(get);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String webData = "";

                while((webData = reader.readLine()) != null){
                     Log.i("data", webData);
                     JSONObject myAwway = new JSONObject(webData);

                    JSONObject data = myAwway.getJSONObject("data");
                    Log.i("data", data.toString());
                    JSONObject travelDate = data.getJSONObject("travel_date");
                    JSONObject from = data.getJSONObject("from");
                    JSONObject to = data.getJSONObject("to");
                    JSONObject alright = data.getJSONObject("alight");
                    JSONObject board = data.getJSONObject("board");
                    JSONArray passenger = data.getJSONArray("passenger");

                    al_texts = data.getString("train_name");
                    Log.i("data", al_texts);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return al_texts;

    }
}
```

here I'm showing/returning only a string(train name).Like this you can show every details .

this is your modified code and working fine.